# Why does indexing an explicitly typed vector fail with a type inference error?

Tags: types, rust

In the [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=98a8464a62f5a97aa62fc4c93761b213) below, I generate a vector and then use it as content for a closure:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = {
        let xs: Vec<(usize, usize)> = Vec::new();
        // populate xs
        move |i, j| xs[j].1 - xs[i].0
    };
    let x = f(1usize, 2usize);
}
```

Why this does code fail to compile with a type inference error although the vector is explicitly typed?

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:5:21
  |
5 |         move |i, j| xs[j].1 - xs[i].0
  |                     ^^^^^ cannot infer type
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[i]` syntax in Rust comes from implementing the [`std::ops::Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E).

That trait looks like this:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> 
where
    Idx: ?Sized, 
{
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

You can implement `Index` for a type multiple times, each with a different type for the `Idx` parameter. `Vec` supports as many different indexing mechanisms as possible by using a blanket implementation of `Index`:

```
impl<T, I> Index<I> for Vec<T>
where
    I: SliceIndex<[T]>,
```

This will work for any type that also has a `SliceIndex` implementation, which includes `usize`, as you were trying to use, but also range types, like `Range<usize>` (e.g. `0..5`) and `RangeFrom<usize>` (e.g. `0..`). Inside the closure, the compiler doesn't know *which* implementation of `Index` is going to be used, and each possibility could have a different `Output` type, which is why it can't infer a single type there.

You can fix it by annotating the arguments of the closure:

```
let f = {
    let xs: Vec<(usize, usize)> = Vec::new();
    //
    move |i: usize, j: usize| xs[j].1 - xs[i].0
};
let x = f(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I explicitly type 1 and 2 as `1usize`, `2usize`, so it knows exactly which implementation to use. It still doesn't work. I must explicitly type the parameters. Why is that?

Comment: @Listerone. Because `f` is generic, and therefore needs to work for any possible index type. Declaring the actual type to `usize` _inside_ `f` effectively stops it being generic.  Declaring the type _outside_ of `f` just chooses the type for that call - but `f` still needs to work for all the other types.