# Why does this closure argument need an explicit type?

Tags: types, rust

Consider the following working [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85fa3c7dfb1f7cea5b40df9888e95d32):

```rust
fn f() {
    let xs = vec![(0, 0)];
    let f = |j| xs[j];
    let y = f(0usize);
}
```

The following [variation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2059bc39f19ead1e093597858bc7476) does not compile:

```rust
fn f() {
    let xs = vec![(0, 0)];
    let f = |j| xs[j].0;
    let y = f(0usize);
}
```

It fails as follows:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     let f = |j| xs[j].0;
  |                 ^^^^^ cannot infer type
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

To fix it, one must annotate `j`:

```rust
fn f() {
    let xs = vec![(0, 0)];
    let f = |j: usize| xs[j].0;
    let y = f(0usize);
}
```

The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#closure-type-inference-and-annotation) says:

> Closures don’t require you to annotate the types of the parameters or
>   the return value like fn functions do.

Why must `j` be explicitly typed?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611350/why-does-indexing-an-explicitly-typed-vector-fail-with-a-type-inference-error) suggested by @Stargateur, Rust needs to know the type of the index so that it can determine the type of the result. In your first example, this is not an issue because you don't use `xs[j]` nor the result of the closure, so the compiler feels free to leave them as "some as yet undefined type" and optimizes them away without ever needing to know the type.

In your second example however, you try to access `xs[j].0`, for which the compiler needs to know the type of `xs[j]` in order to know what to do with the `.0`.

Comment: _compiler needs to know the type of xs[j] in order to know what to do with the .0_ - [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be16af91a3a5e2ecff0fb69fa8f36246) shouldn't compile either then ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden in your example, the compiler sees that `y` is never used, so I assume it doesn't try to fully typecheck the rhs expression. In the OP's case, `xs[j].0` is used as the return value from the closure. I assume the compiler cannot optimize as easily across function (or closure) boundaries, which is why it doesn't see that said return value is never used and can be ignored.

Comment: Nope still works with [printing y](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f5f277e41ecfd82873c431a336f4a06). From my point, compiler is not able to find the type of `index(_)`'s input from a type of `index(_)`'s output. This is normal because **output** can be anything according to implementation of `SliceIndex` to the **input** but it also looks like it is not inferring  the input type from this line `f(0usize)` , maybe the question should be why it is not inferring from  `f(0usize)`?

Comment: If it is about line order it explains why `f(0usize).0` works because input type is already known. But i don't know how type checker algorithm works.

Comment: Good point. I don't know how it works in detail either, but this isn't the first time that I've seen it work better when type information flows forward rather than backward.